# Looping over all files of certain extension in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a small script that unzips all the `*.zip` files in the current directory to extract only `*.srt` files  directory to a newly created directory. It then loops over all the `*.mkv` files in the current directory to get their name and then changes `subs/*.srt` file name to produce a new file name that is exactly as `*.mkv` file name.
The script works when there is one zip file and one mkv file but when there are more files it produces bad filenames. <s>I cannot track why this is the case.</s> Now I figured out when this is the case.

**EDIT**

I managed to narrow down the scenarios when file names are changed in erroneous way.
Let's say in a current directory we have three *.mkv files: (sorted alphabetically)

```
$ ls -1a *.mkv
Home.S06E10.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.mkv 
Home.S06E11.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.mkv
Home.S06E12.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.mkv
```

and three *.srt files:

```
$ ls -1a *.srt
Home.S06E10.srt 
Home.S06E11.BDRip.X264-PRINTER.srt 
Home.S06E12.BDRip.X264-PRINTER.srt
```

When I run the script, I get:

```
subs/Home.S06E10.srt -> subs/Home.S06E10.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.srt
subs/Home.S06E10.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.srt -> subs/Home.S06E11.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.srt
subs/Home.S06E11.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.srt -> subs/Home.S06E12.1080p.BluRay.x264-PRINTER.srt
```

**As you see, `Home.S06E10.srt` is used twice**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p subs
mkdir -p mkv-out
mkdir -p subs-bak
# unzip files, maybe there are subtitles in it...
for zip in *.zip; do
    if [ -f "$zip" ]; then
        unzip "$zip" -d subs "*.srt" >/dev/null
    fi
done

# move all subtitles to subs catalog
for srt in *.srt; do
    if [ -f "$srt" ]; then
        mv "*.srt" subs
fi
done

mkvCount=(*.mkv)
srtCount=(subs/*.srt)

if [ ${#mkvCount[@]} != ${#srtCount[@]} ]; then
    echo "Different number of srt and mkv files!"
    exit 1
fi

for MOVIE in *.mkv; do
    for SUBTITLE in subs/*.srt; do
        NAME=$(basename "$MOVIE" .mkv)
        SRT="subs/$NAME.srt"
        if [ ! -f "$SRT" ]; then
            echo "$SUBTITLE -> ${SRT}"
            mv "$SUBTITLE" "$SRT"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Neat and nice effort on the script(`^1`). Can you show us the malformed names that you mention?

Comment: `mv "*.srt" subs` is certainly an error. You might want to try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human help.

Comment: @tripleee: spellcheck did not report that surprisingly

Comment: @lnian thanks for this. I will update my post with relevant information.

Comment: @menteith: You have the error on line 16 as @tripleee pointed out, it should be  `mv "$srt" subs`

Comment: Actually not using a loop at all would be even better.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes in fact. `srtCount=(subs/*.srt); (( ${#srtCount[@]} )) && mv "${srtCount[@]}" sub` would suffice no?

Comment: In the final loop, I'm guessing you don't mean to move all the subtitles to the first movie, and then not have any left for subsequent iterations of the loop. Is this the error you are referring to? We can't really guess without a description of the actual problem.

Comment: @lnian or just `mv *.srt subs/` (without the double quotes, which would make the script attempt to move a file named literally `*.srt`) and maybe exit in case of error.

Comment: @lnian @tripleee I think `mv "*.srt"` was responsible for the bug since `mv *.srt` works for a single file. @triplee how would you change the code to remove the need for a loop?

Comment: I imagine maybe you want to loop over pairs of values, but without a description of what the code is supposed to do, we are in the dark here.

Comment: I can confirm that the above-mentioned command was responsible for the bug. I will paste my whole script.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You are not supposed to update the question to provide an answer, though you are very welcome to post an *answer* with the fixed script.

Comment: It was you who provided the answer. Perhaps you could write one? However, I'm still testing whether this was the only bug.

Comment: Your final loop seems wrong. You are taking an arbitrary `.srt` file and renaming it to a possibly unrelated movie. Your final code will probably give you one subtitle file per movie, but they may all be for the wrong movies.

Comment: @giusti Yes, it seems. It works for certain files and don't for other.

Comment: Your problem statement is a bit strange to me. You say you want to produce a subtitle file that is the same name as a movie file, but based on what? What is the contents of the Zip files and what patterns do your files follow?

Comment: In zip file there is one *.srt file. My aim is as follows: the last loop takes one mkv file and one srt file and then it continues until last file. As to the pattern, each pair of mkv-srt could be different but that have (at least) one similarity: S01E01 part (numbers are different for each movie).

Comment: @giusti Why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be relying on the lexicographical order of the files to associate one SRT with one MKV. If all you have are season-episode files for the same series, then I suggest a completely different approach: iterate a season and an episode counters, then generate masks in the form S##E## and find a movie and a subtitle files. If you find them, you move them.

```
for season in {01..06}; do
  for episode in {01..24}; do
    # Count how many movies and subtitles we have in the form S##E##
    nummovies=$(find -name "*S${season}E${episode}*.mkv" | wc -l)
    numsubs=$(find -name "*S${season}E${episode}*.srt" | wc -l)
    if [[ $nummovies -gt 1 || $numsubs -gt 1 ]]; then
      echo "Multiple movies/subtitles for S${season}E${episode}"
      exit 1
    fi

    # Skip if there is no movie or subtitle for this particular
    # season/episode combination
    if [[ $nummovies -eq 0 ]]; then
      continue
    fi
    if [[ $numsubs -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo "No subtitle for S${season}E${episode}"
      continue
    fi

    # Now actually take the MKV file, get its basename, then find the
    # SRT file with the same S##E## and move it
    moviename=$(find -name "*S${season}E${episode}*.mkv")
    basename=$(basename -s .mkv "$moviename")
    subfile=$(find -name "*S${season}E${episode}*.srt")
    mv "${subfile}" "${basename}.mkv"
  done
done
```

If you don't want to rewrite everything, just change your last loop:

1. Drop the inner loop
2. Take the movie name instead and use `sed` to find the particular S##E## substring
3. Use `find` to find one SRT file like in my code
4. Move it

This has the benefit of not relying on hard-coded number of seasons/episodes. I guessed six seasons and no season with more than 26 episodes. However I thought my code would do and would look more simple.

Make certain that there will be exactly one SRT file. Having zero or more than one file will probably just give an error from `mv`, but it's better to be safe. In my code I used a separate call to `find` with `wc` to count the number of lines, but if you are more knowledgeable in bash-foo, then perhaps there's a way to treat  the output of `find` as an array instead.

In both my suggestions you can also drop that check for # movies = # subtitles. This gives you more flexibility. The subtitles  can be in whatever directories you want, but the movies are assumed to the in the CWDIR. With `find` you can also use the `-or` operator to accept other extensions, such as AVI and MPG.

Comment: This is a great solution, much better than my own! Thanks!